# Implementation of DHTMLX / DayPoilet or FullCalendar

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar, dhtmlx, daypilot-scheduler

Can i implement DHTMLX / DayPoilet or FullCalendar in our Asp.Net MVC using Angularjs freely for hospital rooms booking scheduler as on one side we have rooms while on other side we have time like
https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/
or
http://roombooking.scheduler-net.com/ (clickin on rooms button)

Comment: Of course you can

Comment: Thank sir but the product that we are building is live Web based for hospitals is there any issue after hosting live?

Comment: Why would there be? it's all just html and javascript

Comment: Well if it requires a license you need to get that license.

Comment: Resource recommendations are off-topic here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Standard edition of dhtmlxScheduler for your project. The Standard edition is distributed under GNU GPLv2 and can be downloaded for free. Please note that in case of using GPL version, your whole project should be open source and licensed under GNU GPL v2: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html 
If you can't or don't want to license your project under GNU GPLv2, you should purchase the license.

Comment: i have implemeted it in asp.net Mvc via Nuget and work good for some days  but no give an error as "Couldn't verify evaluation period. <br> Please contact us here http://scheduler-net.com/free-evaluation-support.aspx or send us an email schedulernet@dhtmlx.com"